# Shortest Path Algorithm in a partial graph

Tags: graph, path, heuristics, shortest, large-data

I am recursively building a graph in java using the graphstream library.. however this graph is so huge so that the recursion is very deep and this ends in stackoverflow. Believe me, even an iteration wouldn't solve my problem.. I will just get a runtime error down the road.

My goal is to use a search algorithm such as Disjktra or A* or whatsoever on the graph in the end.

As I dont have the whole graph, I have been looking in the literature for things such as a shortest path algorithm in a partial maps; use of heuristics I couldn't find much.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me some hints (papers, ideas; an implementation would be a jackpot!!!! :-D) I have looked at algorithms such as PHA* or some others..

Comment: i don't think a shortest path algorithm on a partial graph will be of any help as each new edge may invalidate all results hitherto compiled. i also do not understand why iteration will kill you too - just make sure that the current dfs root path is allocated from the heap and not from the stack (eg. by using `new` instead of automatic vars) and you will be fine unless you literally have billions of nodes. could it be that your actual problem is a non-detection of cycles in your code, possibly with negative weights ?

Comment: I would look into algorithms that process the **complete** graph reading and writing files, without attempting to load all of it into memory; for example, you can easily perform breadth-first shortest path search by sorting nodes according to distance from the starting point.

Comment: @collapsar: Thank you for the idea. Iteration would kill me as I have a lot of nodes. Could go up to billions.. Yes. And I have double-triple check my code: I am sure that I have no loop in there. That is why I thought that the use of heuristics should/may help me get A solution...

Comment: @LorenzoGatti: I will take a look at your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @pro: did you find a solution for this after? what was it?

Comment: @Jeff: I know this post is very old... But I solved it back then using a 1990 Algorithm, from Korf, R. E. (1990) "Real-time heuristic search" Can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.137.1955&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this post is very old... But I solved it back then using a 1990 Algorithm, from Korf, R. E. (1990) "Real-time heuristic search" Can be found here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.137.1955&rep=rep1&type=pdf